# Graphing categorical data types

Tags: r

I'm trying to graph some data and calculate the correlation.  Can anyone recommend a package that could help?

This is my data, all the packages I've tried so far can't compute the correlation.

I can work it out if it wasn't categorical data, but I'm stuck with the category (Lucy or Mark)

```
data = structure(list(Score = c(31L, 97L, 68L, 10L, 80L, 19L, 76L, 12L, 
0L, 41L, 64L, 45L, 99L, 93L, 10L, 21L, 30L, 13L, 49L, 30L, 56L, 
42L, 53L, 69L, 76L, 72L, 77L, 10L, 69L, 79L, 20L, 83L, 76L, 24L, 
59L, 90L, 31L, 83L, 81L, 21L, 53L, 3L, 49L, 88L, 93L, 32L, 12L, 
72L, 1L, 45L, 89L, 78L, 38L, 60L, 95L, 79L, 75L, 44L, 18L, 67L, 
7L, 27L, 44L, 100L, 6L, 76L, 40L, 17L, 37L, 50L, 38L, 84L, 51L, 
8L, 25L, 49L, 29L, 20L, 74L, 82L, 85L, 0L, 46L, 33L, 65L, 55L, 
98L, 37L, 95L, 68L, 94L, 78L, 97L, 68L, 92L, 65L, 33L, 34L, 64L, 
65L), Tutor = c("Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", 
"Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", 
"Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", 
"Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", 
"Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", 
"Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", 
"Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Lucy", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", 
"Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", 
"Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", 
"Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", 
"Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", 
"Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", 
"Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ggplot is really one of the best plotting packages in R. I would highly recommend learning it more in-depth.

```
library(ggplot2)
```

Some examples using your data:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Score, fill = Tutor)) + 
geom_histogram(position = "identity", alpha = 0.5)
```

or

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Tutor, y = Score)) + geom_boxplot()
```

To the more statistical part of your question, I would recommend reading Alexey Grigorev answer: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/893/how-to-get-correlation-between-two-categorical-variable-and-a-categorical-variab